# BASH script - How to simulate user input for password

Tags: bash, scripts, password, input

I'm trying to make a bash script used to unlock an external drive which is password-protected by WD proprietary software.
Since I'm combining this with other bash scripts, **I need it to take the password provided at the beginning** with `read -s -p "Enter WD password: " wdpass` **and use it when prompted by the WD script**.

This is what I have so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo blkid #only need this to get the sudo password right away
wait
read -p "Enter drive ID (ie. sda): " driveid
read -s -p "Enter WD password: " wdpass

sudo apt install python3 python3-dev python3-pip git; sudo pip3 install git+https://github.com/evox95/wdpassport-utils
sudo pip3 install --user git+https://github.com/crypto-universe/py_sg
cd ~; wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/evox95/wdpassport-utils/master/wdpassport-utils.py

sudo ~/wdpassport-utils.py --unlock --device /dev/$driveid
expect "[wdpassport] password for /dev/${driveid}: "
send "$wdpass"
wait
```

I also tried the following combinations instead of `expect` and `send` (but nothing worked):

- `sudo ~/wdpassport-utils.py --unlock --device /dev/$driveid <(echo "$wdpass")`
- `echo "$wdpass"`
- `echo $wdpass`
- `"$wdpass"`
- `$wdpass`

Comment: So you did try: `sudo ~/wdpassport-utils.py --unlock --device /dev/$driveid <(echo "$wdpass")` already?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Yes, I get `error: unrecognized arguments: /dev/fd/63`

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do here. You are trying to automate password input, yet you are still reading the password manually from the keyboard. I don't understand this. If you could explain what explicitly you are trying to achieve, I can help you to automate this with Expect.

Comment: I came here looking for a way to `echo` out of an `expect-script`. `exec echo testbla` works, but produces no output unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `expect` extension to Tcl. It is intended for such automation tasks and more. There is a whole book ([Exploring Expect](https://tsapps.nist.gov/publication/get_pdf.cfm?pub_id=821307)) written about it and [a rich wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect)

[In my comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1328268/bash-script-how-to-simulate-user-input-for-password/1328269#comment2263795_1328269), I stressed the important difference between an expect and a bash script. In this case, it should be `expect` script, here is an example:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f 
spawn ssh aspen 
expect "password: " 
send "PASSWORD\r" 
expect "$ " 
send "ps -ef |grep apache\r" 
expect "$ " 
send "exit\r"
```

You will have to read some guides, for example [Automating with Expect Scripts from admin-magazine.com](https://www.admin-magazine.com/Articles/Automating-with-Expect-Scripts).

Answer (score 0):

The `wdpassport-utils.py` script you are referring to uses Python `getpass.getpass()` function to get the password. Maybe the simplest method would be to just change this with your bash script (eg. using `sed`) to `input()` (which will read input from stdin) before calling `wdpassport-utils.py`, and then use the line mentioned above:

```
sudo ~/wdpassport-utils.py --unlock --device /dev/$driveid <(echo "$wdpass")
```

or, in more common form:

```
echo "$wdpass" | sudo ~/wdpassport-utils.py --unlock --device /dev/$driveid
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I think changing the python script with the commands that you mentioned is a bit over my skills at the moment so I might just leave it as is.

Comment: Unfortunately, this gives me `Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.` and no input is received.

Comment: @Cadoiz I wonder where the `wdpassport-utils.py` script is requesting a terminal, because at first look I can't see it anywhere in the code (assuming all calls to `getpass` are removed), but maybe it's something in the dependent modules, I don't know. Anyway, if this doesn't work, you should stick to using `expect`, but not the way you did in your original example, as that's not the way one uses `expect`. Again, try to describe in plain words what are you trying to do, then I could try to change your script.